# hive string yymmdd to date type yyyymmdd

Tags: hive, hiveql

i have to convert this from string to date like this:

`TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DATE_TIME,1,6),'YYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') as HI_DATE`

I already try this format:

to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP( substr(date_time,1,6), 'yyMMdd' ),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))
but it returns NULL

What went wrong? How to make this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify `hh:mm:ss` in `to_date`. If you want the time you should use `to_timestamp`.

```
to_date(
    from_unixtime(
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 
            substr(date_time, 1, 6),
            'yyMMdd'
        ),
        'yyyy-MM-dd'
    )
)
```